# Upload files with Apache

Tags: html, c, apache, http

I'm writing a CGI program in C to get an uploaded file through HTTP multipart/form-data.

How is that Apache handles file uploads? How can I get the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an established CGI library, such as [cgic](http://www.boutell.com/cgic/), which has `cgiFormFileName`  method for handling uploaded files.